# Espresso UI Test Issue

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am Using **Espresso** for My UI testing. I have a issue with data loading.

Let say In my Normal app Flow

**ActivityA --> ActivityB**

In my **ActivityA** I am fetching some data from the server and store it in my **SingleTonClass**. In **ActivityB** I am getting the data from the same **SingleTon** and showing in my views.

But while Testing with **Espresso** for **ActivityB** it crashes *because I have not loaded any data to my SingleTon Class.*

So how can I load data before **ActivityB** start in Espresso

Answer (score 0):

For that you can user **Annotation**  `@Before`

#### see this [link for info](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
   // set up dummy your data that is required for test
}
```

#### More [about @Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html)